# jquery - get li value on button click

Tags: jquery

i wish to get the li value when the button beside it is clicked. if the button beside apple is clicked i should get apple on an alert box. i,ve been stuck on this for a day now. any help is appreciated.

```
  <ul>
  <li>apple<input type="button" value="show">.      
  <li>jam<input type="button" value="show">.   
  <ul>
```

jquery

```
  $("input[type=button]").click(function()
  {
   alert( $(this).parent().text());
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should close the `li` tags:

```
<ul>
  <li>apple<input type="button" value="show"></li>    
  <li>jam<input type="button" value="show"></li>
</ul>
```

Edit: the script works without closing the li's, sounds that jQuery is not loaded correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/D9Jv7/1/